# What's the running time for quicksort if we select pivot with certain probability

Tags: algorithm, time, quicksort

If we need to pick pivot x for quicksort at random, with probability 0.5, x is the median; with probability 0.5, x is the minimum. I understand the running time when choosing the minimum value is O(n^2) and the running time when choosing the median value is O(n logn). If we combine them together, will the total running time still be O(n logn)?

Comment: 1) "with probability 0.5, x is the median" – sure about this? 2) "the running time of choosing minimum value is O(n^2)" and "the running time of choosing minimum value is O(n log n)" – that seems oddly self-contradictory.

Comment: If you *alternate* between choosing the median and choosing the minimum, then the running time is approximately twice the time versus always choosing the median. Choosing the minimum does approximately nothing, and choosing the median approximately divides the array by two. So the expected running time is still O(n logn).

Comment: @user3386109 It seems to make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice calculation about a good split and a bad split in Corman et. al. When the good split followed by bad split the running time will be O(nlogn).

Even, when the split occur 10/100 all the time, the running time will be O(nlogn).

If your question is; with 1/2 probability there is a good split and with 1/2 probability bad split, the answer will be the expected running time is O(nlogn). Because there are always a case that with very bad luck, we will have bad split.